# Сравнение массивов в Юнит Тестах C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Есть массив, который необходимо сравнить с эталоном.

Пробовал через Assert.AreEqual:

```
Assert.AreEqual<int[]>(_test.arr, _testRight.arr);
```

но при этом выходит ошибка при тестировании: `Ошибка в Assert.AreEqual. Ожидается: <System.Int32[]>. Фактически: <System.Int32[]>.`

Попробовал сравнить сначала длину, потом в цикле каждый элемент, но тогда на трехмерном массиве возникает загвоздка:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _test.arr2.Length; i++ )
{
    Assert.AreEqual(_test.arr2[i].Length, _testRight.arr2[i].Length);
    ....
```

C# требует 3 параметра в arr2.

**Как сравнить массивы?**

Comment: Какой фреймворк используете?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для коллекций и массивов есть:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual();
```

Comment: работает ) буду знать теперь )

Answer (score 5):

Посоветую вам испльзовать фреймворк [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) для юнит-тестов.
[Equality Asserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.4).
В самом низу написано как сравниваются коллекции:

> **Comparing Arrays and Collections**
>
> Since version 2.2, NUnit has been able
>   to compare two single-dimensioned
>   arrays. Beginning with version 2.4,
>   multi-dimensioned arrays, nested
>   arrays (arrays of arrays) and
>   collections may be compared. Two
>   arrays or collections will be treated
>   as equal by Assert.AreEqual if they
>   have the same dimensions and if each
>   of the corresponding elements is
>   equal.

Ну и [вот тут есть ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188088/how-do-you-unit-test-if-two-jagged-arrays-are-equal) как сравнивать массивы без использования сторонних фрейморков.

Comment: перейдя по ссылке, а дальше по ссылке узнал про `arr2.GetLength(0)`, в итоге удалось написать цикл сравнения :)

спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 4):

А что мешает написать собственные функции сравнения?

Например:

```
static bool IsEqual<T>(T[][][] l, T[][][] r) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return (l.Length == r.Length) &&
           l.Zip(r, (litem, ritem) => IsEqual(litem, ritem)).All(b => b);
}

static bool IsEqual<T>(T[][] l, T[][] r) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return (l.Length == r.Length) &&
           l.Zip(r, (litem, ritem) => IsEqual(litem, ritem)).All(b => b);
}

static bool IsEqual<T>(T[] l, T[] r) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return (l.Length == r.Length) &&
           l.Zip(r, (litem, ritem) => litem.Equals(ritem)).All(b => b);
}
```

и т. д.

Comment: @VladD `l.Zip` что означает?

Comment: @IVsevolod: `l.Zip(r, f)` означает, что для каждой соответствующей пары элементов в `l` и `r` (`l[0]` и `r[0]`, `l[1]` и `r[1]`, и т. д.) вычисляется функция `f`, и последовательность вычисленных значений даёт результирующую последовательность. Вот [документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx).

Comment: @VladD это стандартная функция?, или надо ее самому писать?, или с какого-либо фреймворка? просто у меня ругается на Zip

Comment: @VladD для одномерных массивов можно попроще 

    return (l.Length == r.Length) && l.SequenceEqual(r);

Еще решарпер подсказывает что вместо лямбды можно просто указать имя метода

    return (l.Length == r.Length) && l.Zip(r, IsEqual).All(c => c);

После этого будет полный Linq-Fu

Comment: @IronVbif: спасибо, не знал насчёт `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: @IVsevolod: Это было LINQ, вы наверное забыли сказать `using System.Linq;`. В любом случае, рецепт от @IronVbif лучше.